# How to get 'inline' images to be all in one row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get the images to take up as little space as possible.
It seems like the reason they're taking up space is because I do a 50% transform, but I'd like the remaining whitespace not to take up room on the page.

In the first row, there should be room for at least 3 bills (5,50,100) if not all 4.

How can I make them all fit?

[image]

Here is my code:

**App.css**

```
.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-float infinite 3s ease-in-out;
  }
}

.half-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 60%;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
}
.App-header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
}

.App-link {
  color: rgb(112, 76, 182);
}

@keyframes App-logo-float {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px)
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { Counter } from './features/counter/Counter';
import './App.css';

import fifty from './img/fifty.png'
import five from './img/five.png'
import hundred from './img/hundred.png'
import loonie from './img/loonie.png'
import ten from './img/ten.png'
import toonie from './img/toonie.png'
import twenty from './img/twenty.png'


const randomInt = ( lo, hi ) => {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * hi )
  }
const getRandomCash = () => {
  return {
    loonie: randomInt(0, 3),
    toonie: randomInt(0,3),
    five: randomInt(0,3),
    ten: randomInt(0,3),
    twenty: randomInt(0,3),
    fifty: randomInt(0,3),
    hundred: randomInt(0,3)
  }
}

const values = {
  loonie: 1,
  toonie: 2,
  five: 5,
  ten: 10,
  twenty: 20, 
  fifty: 50,
  hundred: 100
}

const images = { loonie, toonie, five, ten, twenty, fifty, hundred }

function App() {

  const [cash, setCash] = useState(getRandomCash());

  console.log(cash);

  let items = Object.keys(cash).map(
    key => Array(cash[key]).fill(key)
  ).flat()

  console.log(items);

  let imageDivs = items.map( item => {
    return (
      <div style={{width:'auto', height:'auto'}}>
      <img style={{transform:'scale(0.5)'}} src={images[item]} alt="" >
      </img>
      </div>
    )
  })

  //console.log(imageDivs)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div class="half-container">
        <div class="left">
        {imageDivs}
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        <div style={{margin:'30px'}}>
        <h3>How much money?</h3>
        <input type="text"/>

        <div style={{marginTop:'20px'}}>
        <button onClick={() => setCash(getRandomCash())}>
        New Wallet
        </button>
        <button>
        Submit
        </button>
        </div>

        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why are you scaling them down using a transform, rather than just giving them a percentage width?

Comment: How would I give them a percentage width without making the width correspond do the parent div?

Comment: If you know the width of the images, say 200px, you could just give them a width of 100px; or if you wanted them to be a quarter of the width of the container you could give them a width of 25%; or you could give them a width proportionate to the viewport: e.g. 10vw.

Comment: Nevertheless, I want to get rid of the space between each image, how can I do that?

Comment: If you absolutely need to scale them with a transform, you could put the transform on a parent class. The problem is though that they wont wrap in the space as you expect them too. If 3 images fit in a row, you wont get 6 images fitting if you scale them down by a half, because the transform is applied after layout is done.

Answer (score 0):

You Can go with bootstrap Grid row Columns rather than transforming it like this

```
let imageDivs = items.map( item => {
return (
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <img src={images[item]} alt="" >
  </img>
  </div>
)
```

})

and also dont forget to add row class

```
<div class="row left">
        {imageDivs}
        </div>
```